# How do you embed a Python 2.7 game requiring pygame into a website?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame

I have a Python 2.7 program with Pygame 2.7 which I wanted to embed into a website. How would you do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't. Pygame isn't a web based technology for games. If that's one of your main platforms, look into HTML5 based frameworks instead (or a platform that can export its runtime and content to HTML5).

Comment: Would it be possible to compile it into a Windows executable file and then embed it onto a website? Thanks.

Comment: You can ask your users to download the executable file, but no, your users wouldn't (.. shouldn't, etc.) run untrusted code from a regular executable.